# Internet Explorer shows error when downloading excel file in SSL site

Tags: asp.net

I get the following error when downloading excel file in SSL site:

```
Internet Explorer cannot download xxxx.aspx from mysite.com.  
Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.
```

After googling, I suspect that it's the problem of the response header.
I try the solution in this page and set the header:
http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/1020

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "private";
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at this article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431)  It's from the horse's mouth so to speak :)  We actually just faced this same issue when we switched to a full SSL session.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue,

When I googled it, I found that "no chache" settings in response header i.e. following code is the reason for the issue.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
Response.AppendHeader("max-age", "0")
```

Some of the blogs says, to fix this issue, you should do some modification in Windows registry on Webserver and on all client machines(:O), well it is not feasible to do registry settings on every client machine.

The root cause is no-cache settings in response header, so I just added

```
Response.ClearHeaders()
```

before adding content to be downloaded to the response header. The code is as shown below,

```
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = corspBean.ContentType
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" + fileName + """")
Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)
Response.End()
```

It has fixed the issue.

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with PDF files I wanted to stream.  Even with `Response.ClearHeaders()` I saw Pragma and Cache-Control headers added at runtime. The solution was to clear the headers in IIS (Right-click -> Properties on the page loading the PDF, then "Http headers" tab).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same problem using LocalReport when exporting to excel. 
Just before the

```
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

we added

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
```

and it worked.