# Error message comes ON IE when try to download file

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, excel, model-view-controller

On this page it generates a Excel sheet and allows user to download that. 
But as shown below it does not work properly on IE (both 7 & 8)
this works fine with Firefox, chrome and safari.
Is there any settings we can do on both client side or Server side.

[image]
[image location](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_MAQugvYJZu4/TH4YhbxA8bI/AAAAAAAAAXA/NZBKN5uYjNg/s640/IE%20issue.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the `Response Headers` to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all down to the response headers with SSL. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399203/internet-explorer-shows-error-when-downloading-excel-file-in-ssl-site) to a previous answer to this question

Comment: thank you Mark Baker. Found the solution 

http://gayanonline.blogspot.com/2010/09/download-file-by-ie-error-with-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and wrote a article on that [Download file by IE error with SSL](http://gayanonline.blogspot.com/2010/09/download-file-by-ie-error-with-ssl.html)